# display all files from specific folder from sdcard Android

Tags: android

how can i display all the files (.pdf, .doc, .ppt, .mp4, etc...) inside a folder in sdcard? i want to display their filenames.

here's what i've got:

```
File files = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Downloads/Files/");
File[] list = files.listFiles();

    int lists = files.listFiles().length;
    String qwe = list.toString();

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "list: " + lists);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "names: " + qwe + "\n"); //i want to show their filenames

    for(int i=0; i < questionfiles.listFiles().length; i++){
        if(list[i].isHidden()){
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "hidden path files.."+list[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) with an [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) (ArrayAdapter for istance).

see this as [example](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Creating-Lists-Using-The-Android-Listactivity/)

EDIT: You can print the array content in this way:

```
Log.i(LOG_TAG, Arrays.toString(list));
```

Comment: anyway i can display filenames in the logcat?

Comment: how can i do that? my code only displays the number of files inside the specified folder

Comment: yah, just modified something. having problems now in splitting and filtering filenames